# How do I search or access an account I made in my banking system program?

Tags: java, arrays, object, inheritance

I'm working on a baking system program for a school project which includes the ff. features:

- Creating a new account
- Balance Inquiry
- Deposit
- Withdraw
- Close account

So far here's the code I've written:

```
class BankAccountAndaya {

    private String accountName, address, birthday, contactNumber;

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    //default constructor
    public BankAccountAndaya() {

    }
    
    public BankAccountAndaya(String accountName, String address, String birthday, String contactNumber){
        this.accountName = accountName;
        this.address = address;
        this.birthday = birthday;
        this.contactNumber = contactNumber;
    }

    //accessor
    public String getAccountName() {
        return accountName;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public String getBirthday() {
        return birthday;
    }

    public String getContactNumber() {
        return contactNumber;
    }

    //mutators
    public void setAccountName(String name) {
        this.accountName = name;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    public void setBirthday(String birthday) {
        this.birthday = birthday;
    }

    public void setContactNumber(String contactNum) {
        this.contactNumber = contactNum;
    }

    public void getClientDetails() {
        System.out.print("Enter name: ");
        setAccountName(sc.next());

        System.out.print("Enter address: ");
        setAddress(sc.next());

        System.out.print("Enter birthday (MM/DD/YY): ");
        setBirthday(sc.next());

        System.out.print("Enter contact number: ");
        setContactNumber(sc.next());
    }
}

public class SavingsAccountAndaya extends BankAccountAndaya {

    private int accountNo;
    private double balance, interestRate;

    Random rd = new Random();
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    // default constructor
    SavingsAccountAndaya() {

    }

    // accessors
    public int getAccountNo() {
        return accountNo;
    }

    public double getBalance() {
        return balance;
    }

    public double getInterestRate() {
        return interestRate;
    }

    // mutators
    public void setAccountNo(int acctNo) {
        this.accountNo = acctNo;
    }

    public void setBalance(double bal) {
        this.balance = bal;
    }

    public void setInterestRate(double intR) {
        this.interestRate = intR;
    }

    public boolean validateAcctNumber(int search) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            int listVal = getAccountNo();
            if (search == listVal) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public void balanceInquiry() {
        System.out.print("Enter account number: ");
        int search = sc.nextInt();

        boolean result = validateAcctNumber(search);
        if (result) {
            System.out.println("Client name: " + getAccountName());
            System.out.println("Balance: " + getBalance());
        } else {
            System.out.println("Account number invalid!");
        }
    }

    public void deposit() {
        System.out.print("Enter account number: ");
        int search = sc.nextInt();
        boolean result = validateAcctNumber(search);

        if (result) {
            System.out.print("Enter amount to deposit: ");
            double deposit = sc.nextDouble();
            if (deposit >= 100) {
                balance += deposit;
                interestRate = 0.05 * balance;
                balance += interestRate;

                System.out.println("Amount deposit successful!");
                System.out.println("Updated balance: " + balance);
            } else {
                System.out.println("Invalid deposit number!");
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("Invalid account number!");
        }
    }

    public void withdraw() {
        System.out.print("Enter account number: ");
        int search = sc.nextInt();
        boolean result = validateAcctNumber(search);

        if (result) {
            System.out.print("Enter amount to withdraw: ");
            double withdraw = sc.nextDouble();
            double mainBal = withdraw - balance;
            if (withdraw >= 100 && withdraw < balance && mainBal >= 5000) {
                balance -= withdraw;
                System.out.println("Amount withdrawn successful!");
                System.out.println("Updated balance: " + balance);
            } else {
                System.out.println("Invalid  withrawal amount!");
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("Invalid account number!");
        }
    }

    public void closeAccount() {
        System.out.print("Enter account number: ");
        int search = sc.nextInt();
        boolean result = validateAcctNumber(search);

        if (result) {
            setAccountNo(0);
            setBalance(0);
            setAccountName("");
            setAddress("");
            setBirthday("");
            setContactNumber("");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Invalid account number!");
        }

    }
}

public class ClientAndaya extends SavingsAccountAndaya {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void displayMainMenu() {
        System.out.println("JBank Main Menu");
        System.out.println("[1] New Account");
        System.out.println("[2] Balance Inquiry");
        System.out.println("[3] Deposit");
        System.out.println("[4] Withdraw");
        System.out.println("[5] Client Profile");
        System.out.println("[6] Close Account");
        System.out.println("[7] Exit");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int i = 0;
        SavingsAccountAndaya[] sa = new SavingsAccountAndaya[100];
        Random rd = new Random();
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        int input;
        do {
            displayMainMenu();
            System.out.print("Enter number: ");
            input = sc.nextInt();
            sa[i] = new SavingsAccountAndaya();
            switch (input) {
                case 1:
                    System.out.println("New Account: ");
                    sa[i].getClientDetails();

                    System.out.print("Enter amount to deposit: ");
                    double inDepo = sc.nextDouble();

                    if (inDepo < 5000) {
                        System.out.println("Invalid initial deposit amount!");
                        System.out.println("Amount must be greater than 5000 PHP");
                        System.out.print("Enter amount to deposit: ");
                        inDepo = sc.nextDouble();
                    }

                    sa[i].setBalance(inDepo);

                    // generate account number
                    int ranNo = rd.nextInt(9999);
                    sa[i].setAccountNo(ranNo);
                    System.out.println("Account number: " + sa[i].getAccountNo());
                    i++;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    System.out.println("Balance Inquiry: ");
                    sa[i].balanceInquiry();
                    break;
                case 3:
                    System.out.println("Deposit: ");
                    sa[i].deposit();
                    break;
                case 4:
                    System.out.println("Withdraw: ");
                    sa[i].withdraw();
                    break;
                case 5:
                    System.out.println("Client Profile: ");
                    System.out.println("Account number: " + sa[i].getAccountNo());
                    System.out.println("Accoutn Name: " + sa[i].getAccountName());
                    System.out.println("Address: " + sa[i].getAddress());
                    System.out.println("Birthday: " + sa[i].getBirthday());
                    System.out.println("Contact Number: " + sa[i].getContactNumber());
                    System.out.println("Balance: " + sa[i].getBalance());
                    break;
                case 6:
                    System.out.println("Close Account: ");
                    sa[i].closeAccount();
                    break;
                case 7:
                    break;
                default:
                    System.out.println("Invalid chosen number!");
            }
        } while (input < 6 && input > 0);
    }
}
```

I can't seem to access or search for an account I've created. Whenever I input the account number, it always results to invalid account number even though I've already created an account that has that account number. I think the problem lies with the validateAcctNumber method:

```
public boolean validateAcctNumber(int search) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            int listVal = getAccountNo();
            if (search == listVal) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

It was also mentioned in the instructions to use exception to validate inputs.
How can I solve this problem? Thank you for your help.

Comment: Your first clue is that "i" in your for loop is never used in the loop. Was your intent to be looping here? If so, what are you looping for?

Comment: @ruggierin the "i" is  only ever used at the new account option. I wanted to loop the main menu until it is exited. Can you give me more hints on how to approach this because I'm quite new at java?

Comment: The "i" is never used in your validateAcctNumber method. Something is wrong with your logic there. You have a LOT of code here which is probably why you haven't received many replies. I suggest you break it down one piece at a time based on your bullet points in your opening. First, do the "Creating a new account" and see if you get errors there and move forward only after that works. If you get stuck there, you can greatly minimize the code in your question and we can help from there.

Comment: Don't get me wrong, "i" doesn't have to be used in a for loop but in your case it doesn't make sense to loop 100 times on that logic. Why would you want to get the account number 100 times and compare it against the input parameter "search" 100 times?